# use setTimeout for addEventListener()

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make my program to call a gameOver() function if the player does not click the elements within 5 seconds. I have the javascript listening for a click event and pushing the data into another function handleClick() (this function just checks if the sequence is correct). I am unsure as to add a timeOut so that if the user doesnt click within 5 seconds i call another function called gameOver()

```
tileCon.addEventListener('click', e => {
const { tile } = e.target.dataset;
if (tile) handleClick(tile);
});
```

tileCon is my container for my clickable elements in my index.html.

Im thinking I would have to create a separate function but i am unsure how to implement it

Comment: Within 5 seconds of what? The first click, initialization of the whole game, …?

Comment: 5 seconds since the first click

Comment: Have you tried to create a timeout, and if the element is clicked you just clear the timeout using clearTimeout

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like

```js
const button = document.querySelector(".clickme")

let timer
function timerStart(){
  timer ? clearTimeout(timer) : "";
  timer = setTimeout(gameOver,5000)
  console.log("clicked")
}

function gameOver(){
  console.log("Game Over")
}
button.addEventListener('click',timerStart)
```

```css
.clickme{
  height :2rem;
   width:6rem;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<button class="clickme">Click me </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this piece of code:

```js
let timout;
let isGameStarted = false;
const output = document.getElementById('output');

function startOrContinueGame() {
  if (!isGameStarted) {
    isGameStarted = true;
    timeout = setTimeout(gameOver, 5000);
    output.innerHTML = "Game started!";
  } else {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(gameOver, 5000);
    output.innerHTML = "Game still running.";
  }
}

function gameOver() {
  if (timeout) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  } 
  isGameStarted = false;
  output.innerHTML = "Game over!";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="startOrContinueGame()">Click me</button>
<div id="output">Game not started yet.</div>
```